# Rails bcrypt lost password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, bcrypt

Hi I'm trying to make a forgot password using bcrypt in rails. I've taken the method "forgot_password" described in the bcrypt documentation and made a mailer for it.
I've set this method in my user model like self.forgot_password

I'm trying to call this method in a form just under the login form in sessions/new but I think I don't have the good way to do it.
Here is my form code :

```
<%= form_for :user, :url=>{:action=>"forgot_password"} do |f| %>
  <p>Réintialiser mon mot de passe en renseignant votre email ci-dessous :</p>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder=>"ex: cdupont@gmail.com" %>
          </div>
            <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Me renvoyer un email", :class => 'btn btn-warning'   %></center>
            </div> 
            <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

## assign them a random one and mail it to them, asking them to change it

```
def forgot_password
@user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  random_password = Array.new(10).map { (65 + rand(58)).chr }.join
  @user.password = random_password
  @user.save!
  Mailer.create_and_deliver_password_change(@user, random_password)
end
```

check this out : https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby